# later.js add days to already created schedule

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am using [later.js](http://bunkat.github.io/later/index.html) to create schedules with a start date and an end date. The end date can fall on the same day, next day, second day ... sixth day ahead of the start date. Example of some schedule items

> 2015-03-28 13:00 - 2015-03-28 14:00
>
> 2015-03-29 13:00 - 2015-03-29 14:00
>
> 2015-03-25 13:00 - 2015-04-01 14:00

I have created the first set of schedules - the start dates. I now need to create the second set of schedules - the end dates. Is there any easy way to add days / set a different time to a set of already created schedules?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into similar issue - merging schedules. My use-case requires merging multiple schedules and getting next occurrences. Here's what I ended up with:

```
var later = require('later');

var sched = later.parse.cron('10-11 22 * * *');
var sched2 = later.parse.cron('44 15 * * *');

for(var i = 0; i < sched2.schedules.length; i++){
  var sc = sched2.schedules[i];
  sched.schedules.push(sc);
}
occurrences = later.schedule(sched).next(10);

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(occurrences[i]);
}
```